# Spring MVC @RequestBody for JAXB Domain object AFTER XSLT transform of received XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt, spring-mvc, jaxb

The situation is that a vendor supplied an XML schema for their XML documents that they can submit to my service.  I didn't like their schema and so I wrote my own schema along with an XSLT to transform the received XML. My schema was used with JAXB's xjc tool to generate .java files that bind some pojos into a suitable object model.  If it were not for the fact that a transformation step were needed, this would be trivial to implement in Spring MVC.

The received XML must first be transformed before being mapped onto the JAXB classes.  Roughly analogous to the following snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/receiveXml", method=RequestMethod.POST )
public ResponseEntity<String> receiveXml( @RequestBody String vendorXmlPayload )         {      
  // 1.  Make sure vendorXmlPayload adheres to vendor's schema
  vendorSchema.newValidator().validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(vendorXmlPayload)));

  // 2.  Transform xml payload to my schema
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
  transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(vendorXmlPayload)), new StreamResult(sw))

  // 3.  Validate transformed XML against my schema
  mySchema.newValidator().validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(sw.toString())));

  // 4.  Unmarshall to JAXB-annotated classes
  DomainObject obj = (DomainObject) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(sw.toString())));


  (errors != null) ? return ... HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST : return ..... HttpStatus.OK
}
```

Are there some elegant Spring annotations to condense all of that on the MVC Controller?  Namely is there a way to perform the transform & unmarshal with the @RequestBody annotation or something?  Perhaps like this fictitious snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/receiveXml", method=RequestMethod.POST )
@Transform(transformer="myTransform.xslt")
public ResponseEntity<String> receiveXml( @RequestBody DomainObj domainObj)         
{
  // Process my DomainObj as I normally would
  (errors != null) ? return ... HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST : return ..... HttpStatus.OK
}
```

@InitBinder doesn't quite look like it fits this scenario.  Most "Spring MVC XSLT" searches deal with transforming output rather than input.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt if there is anything like this out of the box, but you should be able to build something reusable along these lines:

Define a new annotation for yourself say @XmlWithTransform, which takes in a parameter of say the xslt location, which you can specify on a controller this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/receiveXml", method=RequestMethod.POST )
    public ResponseEntity<String> receiveXml( @XmlWithTransform(usingxslt="anxsl.xsl")     CustomType customType )
```

Now write a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` which can take in the request body xml, transform it using the xslt argument of annotation and binds it to the type specified as the argument, along these lines:

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.springframework.core.MethodParameter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebDataBinderFactory;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.ModelAndViewContainer;

public class XsltTransformingHandlerMethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver{

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller;
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter){
        return (parameter.getMethodAnnotation(XmlWithTransform.class)!=null);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        XmlWithTransform xmlWithTransform = parameter.getMethodAnnotation(XmlWithTransform.class);
        Class<?> parameterType = parameter.getParameterType();
        String xsltLocation = xmlWithTransform.usingxstl();
        ServletServerHttpRequest servletRequest = new ServletServerHttpRequest(webRequest.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class));
        String xmlFromVendor = IOUtils.toString(servletRequest.getBody(), "UTF-8");

        String xmlInternal = transform(xmlFromVendor, xsltLocation);
        return unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlInternal)));
    }
}
```

and register this argument resolver with Spring MVC:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven> 
   <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <bean class="XsltTransformingHandlerMethodArgumentResolver"></bean>
   </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```